# Improve performance for com4j

Tags: java

I am using it to connect to Quality Center of HP application. I run a big application and memory increase too much, but it does not decrease. It make application has been crashed. does anybody has any solution?

Thanks

Comment: do you register listeners, or make use of unmanaged memory allocations?

Comment: you should really [Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) your application and determine where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running out of memory the first place you need to start is working out what is using the memory, then look at whether that should still exist and if not, why it still exists.

A good staring point is to get a Heap Dump using jmap as explained on [this blog](http://www.objectdefinitions.com/odblog/2008/jmap-and-jstack-getting-a-heap-dump-and-stack-trace-from-a-running-jvm/). A heap dump is a dump of everything currently in memory, so be prepared for a file at least as large as the amount of memory allocated to the VM.

Once you have the heap dump, it can be analyzed with [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). This will be able to tell you what the biggest usages of memory are and walk up and down the chains of references that are preventing things being garbage collected.

Now this is all pure java stuff, so if the problem is in the native components of com4j or the com object its self then this will not help, but it will allow you to eliminate the Java side from your investigation. If it is the com component that is leaking memory then try running it without the java side and see if you can reproduce the memory leak in isolation. At that point you'll need to Native / COM equivalent of the techniques I've just described, but I'm afraid I don't know anything about that.